# Два одинаковых UserControl для разных полей ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestUserControl.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestUserControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbPath"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Content="..." {Binding Path=ChangeCommand} />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

В основном окне есть Grid, который содержит два экземпляра этих UC:

```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <local:MyControl x:Name="TextField1" Grid.Row="0"/>
       <local:MyControl x:Name="TextField2" Grid.Row="1"/>
   </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _field1;
    string _field2;
    ICommand _changeCommand;

    public ICommand ChangeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changeCommand == null)
            {
                _changeCommand = new ChangeCommand();
            }
            return _changeCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _changeCommand = value;
        }
    }


    public string Field1
    {
        get
        {
            return _field1;
        }
        set
        {
            _field1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Field1");
        }
    }

    public string Field2
    {
        get
        {
            return _field2;
        }
        set
        {
            _field2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Field2");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Как правильно привязать Field1 к TextBox-у экземпляра TextField1 а, соответственно, Field2 к TextBox-у TextField2.
Соответственно и ChangeCommand - должна при выполнении, дифференцировать, от какой кнопки она нажата и, допустим, вставлять в Field1 - "A", а в Field2 - "B"

**UPD:** Вариант с *DependencyProperty*

*UserControl:*

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty TextBoxValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TextBoxValue",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ButtonCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MyControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextBoxValueProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextBoxValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно, изменения для основного окна:

```
<local:MyControl x:Name="TextField1" Grid.Row="0" TextBoxValue="{Binding Field1}" ButtonCommand="{Binding ChangeCommand}"/>
<local:MyControl x:Name="TextField2" Grid.Row="1" TextBoxValue="{Binding Field2}" ButtonCommand="{Binding ChangeCommand}"/>
```

В самом UC убрал биндинг команды:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbPath"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
<Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Content="..." />
```

Comment: Ну есть много путей. Самый простой — можно поделить VM на две отдельные. Более сложный путь — положить в UserControl dependency property типа string для отображаемого свойства и устанавливать нужное при помощи привязки (пишу с телефона, попробовать код негде).

Comment: @VladD. Про разбивки на отдельные VM уже думал, но в моем случае, ИМХО, излишнее усложнение архитектуры. А вот про Dependency Property, пока не разобрался, но, думаю - скорее всего это решение подошло бы.

Comment: Окей, давайте попробуем. Вы умеете объявлять DependencyProperty?

Comment: @VladD. Да, привел код в вопросе. Только теперь, как заставить все это работать? Т.е. сейчас нажимаю кнопку, но ничего не происходит. Т.е. надо как-то связать команду с самой кнопкой в UC

Comment: А дальше несложно, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С теми Dependency Property, что описаны в вопросе, дальнейшая часть решения несложна:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbPath"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="{Binding TextBoxValue}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Content="..." Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Почему-то кнопка все-равно не реагирует на нажатие :( и еще, как определить какому текстовому полю соответствует нажатие кнопки, чтобы вставить дифференцированно значение.

Comment: @Sublihim: Так, а сама команда вызывается? Поставьте breakpoint

Comment: Заработала :) Забыл добавить DataContext для Grid в UC. Но как дифференцировать поля? Наверно, что-то надо засунуть в CommandParametr, только не пойму, наверно в самом окне, где команды биндятся к UC?

Comment: @Sublihim: Например, добавить ещё D.P. ID типа object, и привязать в Button `CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"`.

Comment: Хм. Это идея! :) Спасибо!

Comment: @Sublihim: Пожалуйста! Ничего изящнее не придумал, к сожалению.